# Android ROM Development. What does it take?

Tags: android, mobile

I have been developing android apps out of hobby and fun. I want to get more serious about android development. One particular thing that I am very keen on doing (or atleast trying my hand at) is andoroid ROM development for specific handsets. Like, maybe outdated HTC Touch. (Elf/Elfin).

I am at a loss to understand, what does it take to get started in right direction and what does it entails? I would really appreciate your help if you could point me to some resources which would highlight ROM Development for Android specifically. (Fundamentals of ROM development irrespective of OS would help too).

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good forum for that: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=613
There are some good posts there, specially the sticky from Cyanogen has good links, and there is too a basic rom cooker if you want to do simple customizations.

Here's the direct link to Cyanogen's post: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=667298